# In coldfusion compare two queries from different databases

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do I compare two queries from two different databases?

```
<cfquery name="doggyValidationOne" datasource="myDatabaseSource"
            select dogType from databaseOne
</cfquery>



<cfquery name="doggyValidationTwo" datasource="myOtherDatabaseSource"
            select dogType from databaseTwo
</cfquery>
```

I need to inform the user that all dogs in database two exist in database one.
I can do this in sql with

```
select doggy from tableOne minus select doggies from tableTwo
```

How can I accomplish this in coldfusion 10?
I'm thinking maybe creating a list out of each query and comparing the results, but then I can't display the table row information to the user.

Comment: Which DBMS and are the databases on the same server? (Tip: Many things in sql are vendor specific, so it saves time if you always include that information up front in all query questions.)

Comment: I'm "talking about an in memory query ie QoQ"

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much data? If it is a small amount, a `WHERE IN (...)` clause would suffice.

Comment: database one has 10,000 records and slowly growing, database two could have up to 9,000 records at a time, but no more.

Comment: (Edit) Let me rephrase it. How many unique `doggy` values in your QoQ? (I assume it is from your spreadsheet import, correct?).

Comment: Correct. there are 9,000 doggy records.

Comment: databaseOne has 10,000 unique 'doggy' values. databaseTwo, which Imported from my excel sheet can have duplicate 'doggies'. I need to verify all the dogs imported from databaseTwo (excel sheet) already exist in database one, otherwise inform the user of error.

Comment: _"I'm "talking about an in memory query ie QoQ"_ - you're making assumptions about how to solve the problem. The DBMS is relevant; it's entirely possible you can do a WHERE NOT EXISTS with a single query, and there's a good chance that's more efficient than doing it via QoQ.

Comment: Why is the spreadsheet not just imported to a temporary table in database one, then there's no cross-database stuff involved at all.

Comment: I was considering creating a temp table if there is no straightforward solution of doing the compare with coldfusion.

Comment: From your description, there is only one database (you still did not tell us which dbms, btw) and a spreadsheet file you want to import. If that is the case, you should strongly consider importing into a table, and using a JOIN for this. Both from a performance and data integrity perspective (which I suspect may be an issue if "dog type" is not a FK).

Comment: I think that with the number of records you have, using the valuelist from each query to figure out the difference is a good plan.  Once you have a list of dogs you want to output to the user, just loop through it and display it.  In fact, you could display as you go instead of creating another list.

Comment: Creating the temp table _is_ the straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not in QoQ, but http://www.cflib.org/udf/querycompare or http://www.cflib.org/udf/queryDiff should do the trick.

Comment: Funny I was actually implementing the first link before I posted, but still testing to see if it works correctly. I really thought this could be done with QoQ, for some reason.